# How to compile a C++03 project that uses a C++11 library API?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, c++03

I am required to use a shared library A and its API which was compiled using C++11. It uses C++11 features like `std::mutex` and `std::shared_ptr` in its API. I have no control over library A.

However, I am also being required to compile my code using C++03 which uses library A's API.

I am pretty sure that this cannot be done because I get compiler errors stating that the uses of `std::mutex`, `std::shared_ptr`, and others in the API are not found. (My understand is, if library A didn't use C++11 specific types then I should be able to do this.)

But I just want to make sure that there isn't something I am not understanding that I need to do in order to compile my code against the C++11 library A.

So the question is, can I compile my code using C++03 against a shared library and its API that uses C++11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An API which exposes *at its edges* any C++11-specific features won't be usable from C++03.  One way you could work around this would be to build a C++11 wrapper for the library which converts all C++11-specific inputs and outputs to C++03-compatible types.  For example if the original C++11 library returns a `std::shared_ptr` from its API, the wrapper library could return a `boost::shared_ptr` or a raw pointer instead.  The "Pimpl" idiom might be helpful when implementing the wrapper, e.g. if you need to make wrappers for smart pointers but can't allow your application code to see `std::shared_ptr` at all.

But the question has to be asked: why not just enable C++11 for your existing code?

Comment: John, I would love to enable C++11 for my existing code. But the people in charge demand that my code be C++03 only. On the other hand they also demand that I use this library. (yes, this is a double standard, and yes it is very frustrating.) I appreciate your input this helps me understand what I need to do.